# Use failover IP as a primary server IP

Tags: ip, unix, freebsd, failover

I bought a dedicated server which has its primary IP blacklisted, I am having a IP failover (`NIC` I believe) I'd like to use as a primary IP instead.

Is action like that possible? if so, what can I do to achieve that?

Comment: If you got your IP blacklisted, you may be able to get a new one from your ISP for cheap or free (provided it hasn't been blacklisted for a very good reason that still persists). For an actual answer to this particular question, I'd have to know what you're using for failover. The answer is probably that you can do this, as your failover IP is most likely just another public IP.

Comment: @SmallLoanOf1M My ISP can't reply for about one week now, I am tired of this since I need to run my services ASAP. Yes, my failover is a public IP , currently it's just being added as an alias.

Comment: If you got blacklisted once, is there not a possibility you will get the new (or failover) IP blacklisted as well? Perhaps worthwhile trying to get off the blacklist.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to give it a try on my own and seems like it its working fine... I've replaced my primary IP with an alias in the `rc.conf` file configuration and set the `defaultrouter` to my failover IP as follows:

```
ifconfig_em0="inet FAILOVER.SERVER.IP.ADDRESS netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast FAILOVER.IP.ADDRESS.255"
defaultrouter="FAILOVER.IP.ADDRESS.254"
ifconfig_em0_alias0="inet ORIGINAL.SERVER.IP.ADDRESS netmask 255.255.255.255"
```

I believe it looks fine...

Comment: Looks fine to me.